# UIimagepicker camera switch control issue in iOS8

Tags: ios8

I am working on UIImagepicker. I found strange, unable to see camera switch control on iOS8, but when i click on top, camera switchs. Is this iOS8 bug or wrong from my side?

But when i check in iOS7, iOS6 able to see camera switch controls.

```
UIImagePickerController *picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
         picker.delegate=self;
         picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera; 
         picker.showsCameraControls=YES;
         [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one. Hope it will be useful.

```
UIImagePickerController *imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imgPicker.delegate = self;
imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentViewController:imgPicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But, did you check on iOS8?